# Handling posts by users? What type of database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Okay so I was wondering how Facebook and other sites like Twitter keep up with user's posts? When a user goes onto the time line and makes a post, i wouldn't imagine that their text and such would be kept in an mySQL database. Their user data might, but I wouldn't imagine their posts would. Can anyone tell me what type of database I should look into? Thanks.

Comment: Why wound't you imagine their text would be kept in mysql database?

Comment: Well all I could think of is that for that to happen you would have to have a table for each user?

Comment: @HarrisonHoward: No. You have a table called `posts` and it has a column like `user_id` which references a row in the `users` table.

Comment: @HarrisonHoward I found your reasoning a bit flawed and odd. Again, creating a table for each user is not such un-doable thing

Comment: you don't want to reference facebook\twitter when you ask a question like this; your not really going to get their traffic and sites like that are likely to be using very different set-ups than the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be kept in a mysql database. If you haven't already, you should read about foreign and primary keys in a db, they create a relationship that connects say a table named `users` to another table named `posts` which might have a column `poster` which is linked to `users` => `id` or something. It's quite easy if you know db relationships

Comment: I guess i can tweek with my db to make it work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Facebook uses a bunch of MySQL databases distributed using sharding; Twitter uses their own database system with a MySQL backend called [FlockDB](https://github.com/twitter/flockdb)<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> I can't explain why there aren't any recent commits, though.